# Como utilizar uma variável no StatefulWidget no flutter

Tags: firebase, variáveis, flutter, dart, firebase-database

Preciso utilizar duas variáveis que eu recebi como parâmetro para colocar no FirebaseFirestore

```
class Addresposta extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  final String idPergunta;
  final String idUser;
  Addresposta ({Key? key, required this.idPergunta, required this.idUser}) : super(key: key);
  AddrespostaState createState() => AddrespostaState();

}

class AddrespostaState extends State<Addresposta> {

  CollectionReference user =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(idUser).collection('Perguntas').doc(idPergunta).collection('resposta_pergunta');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
}
```

Por Exemplo: eu gostaria de colocar as variáveis : final String idPergunta; e final String idUser; dentro do: .doc(idUser) e .doc(idPergunta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe de estado de um StatefulWidget mantém a referência a ele por meio da propriedade `.widget`:

No exemplo do seu código:

```
CollectionReference user =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(widget.idUser).collection('Perguntas').doc(widget.idPergunta).collection('resposta_pergunta');
```

Para mais informações, leia a [documentação oficial](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) (em inglês).

Comment: Deu certo, eu tentei fazer dessa forma antes mas não tinha dado certo, mas é porque eu tinha que colocar dentro do widget build. Obrigado pela resposta